# Как получить/обновить документ во вложенной коллекции mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Здравствуйте!
Имеется коллекция mongo следующего вида

```
    const GroupsShema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [ true, 'Укажите название группы']
    },
    groupInvite: {
        type: String,
        required: [ true, 'Укажите инвайт группы']
    },
    users: [
        {
            author: {
                type: String
            },
            role: {
                type: String
            },
            token: {
                type: String
            },
            login: {
                type: String,
            },
            hash: String,
            salt: String
        }
    ]
   });

GroupsShema.methods.setPassword = function (password) {
    this.users.salt = crypto
        .randomBytes(16)
        .toString('hex');
    this.hash = crypto
        .pbkdf2Sync(password, this.users.salt, 1000, 512, 'sha512')
        .toString('hex');
};

GroupsShema.methods.validPassword = function (password) {
    var hash = crypto
        .pbkdf2Sync(password, this.users.salt, 1000, 512, 'sha512')
        .toString('hex');
    return this.users.hash === hash;
   };
```

Задача в чем - нужно найти группу, в которой есть пользователь из users по инвайту группы ( поле groupInvite ), а затем в этой группе найти пользователя по логину и токену и заполнить остальньные поля (т.е апдейтить поля в 1 документе users.
 + вторая проблема - методы setPassword и validPassword - не рабочие. Тут вообще тьма, как их описать, чтобы они применялись конкретно к документу users, а не groups.

Ваши идеи?

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите этот код.
Сюда уже можете добавить свои методы  конкретной Модели и будет все работать как вам нужно.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(_MONGODB_URL_CONNECT_, {
    server: {
        reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE,
        reconnectInterval: 1000
    }
});
var db = mongoose.connection;



var shemeExample = new Schema({

    test: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
    },
    update_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now 
    },
    create_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now // time create tx
    }
});

var modelTest = mongoose.model("exampleCollection", shemeExample);
```

example save

```
let rowExample = new modelTest(test:'stringSaveExampleBlaBla');
rowExample.save()
    .then((res)=>{console.log('success save',res);})
```

find example find(where)

```
modelTest.find({test:'stringSaveExampleBlaBla'})
     .then((result_rows)=>{console.log('find res rows',result_rows);})
```

find example  update(where,update,options);

```
modelTest.update({test:'stringSaveExampleBlaBla'},{test:'updatetest'},{multi:true,new:true})
     .then((res_updated)=>{console.log('updated info',res_updated);})
```